# How to find multiple elements on a page in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have multiple input HTML tags on same page having same id and name or class,

Now How should I find 2nd or 3rd.. etc input. I can work with arrays so Do we have some function which will return all the textBox(input tag) from that page.

Comment: you will have to use list array and store all values by tag OR xpath depends on your need.

Comment: By the way, having the same id for multiple tags is not a good idea: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you create a list with FindElements, then you can iterate through that list. For example:

```
var allTextBoxes = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("input"));

foreach(var textBox in allTextBoxes)
{
    textBox.DoSomething();
}
```

You can use a for-loop as well:

```
for(int i = 0; i < allTextBoxes.Count; i++)
{
   allTextBoxes[i].DoSomething();
}
```

Or if you want a specific Element, in example the 3rd:

```
allTextBoxes[2].DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Anaxi's answer,

If you are using the PageObject framework you can do it like this and set the `FindsBy` attribute on a property:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "YourId")]
public IList<IWebElement> ListOfWebElements { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about selenium... but to select element of html page you can use HtmlAgilityPack..

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(@"http://example.com");
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='your_class_name']");
```

it will return a list of node that contains your_class_name.. then find and use the one you want.

to select all the input tags from that page you can use

```
foreach (var input in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input"))
{
    //your logic here 
}
```

hope it helps..

Comment: Good answer but I would not recommend mixing HtmlAgilityPack and Selenium, it would just get confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

In C# I use `FindElements` then `ElementAt()`:

```
var foo= Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='your_class_name']"));
var foo2= foo.ElementAt(1);
```

If it's 10 elements with the same ID (which is HORRIBLE) and I'd like to grab the 8th element, I just use `ElementAt(8);` (or index 7 or however you're set up).

It's a tough call. I'd much rather have them fix the code but in some cases that's just not going to happen... at least not in the near future.

Hope this helps.