# Selenium webdriver - clicking an element returned by findElements()

Tags: selenium, webdriver

With selenium webdriver it is possible to write

```
driver.findElement(By.id('div-id')).click();
```

How does it work with multiple elements? For example, following script gives an error 'Cannot read property click of undefined':

```
var rows = driver.findElements(By.css('#table-body tr'));
rows[2].click();
```

Is there any other way but to write

```
driver.findElements(By.css('#table-body tr')).then( function(rows) {
    rows[2].click();
});
```

Comment: Could share your HTML first...and make sure `rows` has two elements...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find few elements, you could try FindElement individually, also i'd try for-loop to select them.

Here are good suggestions for your situation, visit these threads:

[How to find multiple elements on a page in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045240/how-to-find-multiple-elements-on-a-page-in-selenium)

[Selecting multiple elements with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074056/selecting-multiple-elements-with-selenium)